# Ajax.BeginForm that can redirect to a new page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an `@Ajax.BeginForm` for my model which has a boolean value (`@Html.CheckBoxFor`). If this is checked, I want my HttpPost action to redirect to a new page. Otherwise I want it to just continue being an `@Ajax.BeginForm` and update part of the page.

Here is my HttpPost action (Note: Checkout is the boolean value in my model)

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateModel(BasketModel model)
    {
        if (model.Checkout)
        {
            // I want it to redirect to a new page
            return RedirectToAction("Checkout");
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("_Updated");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use JSON and perform the redirect on the client:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateModel(BasketModel model)
{
    if (model.Checkout)
    {
        // return to the client the url to redirect to
        return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Checkout") });
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("_Updated");
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateModel", "MyController", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSuccess", UpdateTargetId = "foo" }))
{
    ...
}
```

and finally:

```
var onSuccess = function(result) {
    if (result.url) {
        // if the server returned a JSON object containing an url 
        // property we redirect the browser to that url
        window.location.href = result.url;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I want to redirect to an action that requires an id parameter to be passed to it.  How would I pass that from my Ajax.BeginForm view?

Comment: I can't get the var onSucess to work.  I loaded these jquery scripts in the view.
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js
jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js
jquery.validate.min.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

Here's the code in the view
@{var onSuccess = function(result) { if (result.url) { window.location.href = result.url; } }
int acntid = Model.AcntId;  }
<h2>Add</h2>
<div id="ShipAdd">

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ShipAdd", new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "onSuccess(acntid)", UpdateTargetId = "ShipAdd", HttpMethod = "Post" }))

Continued.

Comment: Continued.                                                Intellisense says function, result and window are not in context.  Also would this be the proper way to pass a parameter?  Thanks

Comment: The var onSucess needs to be in a <script> tag.  I updated your answer.  I'm still working on the passsing parameter issue if you should have any insight.  Thanks, again

Comment: I posted a new question concerning how to pass a route value                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417668/ajax-beginform-that-can-redirect-to-a-new-page-and-pass-a-parameter

Comment: here is **one liner** `return JavaScript( "window.location = '" + Url.Action("Checkout","Home") + "'" )` check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538523/how-to-get-an-asp-net-mvc-ajax-response-to-redirect-to-new-page-instead-of-inser), hope helps someone.