# Ajax.BeginForm that can redirect to a new page and pass route value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

This link shows how to redirect an @Ajax.BeginForm but not how to pass a route value to the new view.

[Ajax.BeginForm that can redirect to a new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391201/ajax-beginform-that-can-redirect-to-a-new-)
page/9391267#9391267

How would you redirect an @Ajax.BeginForm with a route value?  The equivalent of

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = acntId };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's no different, just use the [`Url` helper overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460294%28v=vs.98%29) with the route values:

```
return Json(new { 
    url = Url.Action("Checkout", 
        new { id = accntId }
    ) 
});
```