# How to fix Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions, other answers does not fix

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

ASP.NET MVC2 view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcMusicStore.ViewModels.PaymentViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    ...
    <form action="<%= Html.Action("PaymentByBankTransfer", "Checkout") %>" >
    <input type="submit" value="Payment by bank transfer" />
    </form>
```

CheckoutController:

```
    public ActionResult PaymentByBankTransfer()
    {
        var order = Session["Order"] as Order;
        ExecCommand(@"update dok set confirmed=true where order={0}", order.OrderId);
        return CheckoutCompleteOK();

        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(HttpContext);
        cart.EmptyCart();
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538523/how-to-get-an-asp-net-mvc-ajax-response-to-redirect-to-new-page-instead-of-inser?lq=1
        return JavaScript("window.location = '/Checkout/CompleteOK'");
    }

    // common method called from other controller methods also
    public ActionResult CheckoutCompleteOK()
    {
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(HttpContext);
        cart.EmptyCart();
        // prevent duplicate submit if user presses F5
        return RedirectToAction("Complete");
    }

   public ActionResult Complete()
    {
        var order = Session["Order"] as Order;
        SendConfirmation(order);
        return View("PaymentComplete", order);
     }
```

pressing form submit button causes exception

```
Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions
```

As code shows most upvoted answer from

[How to get an ASP.NET MVC Ajax response to redirect to new page instead of inserting view into UpdateTargetId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538523/how-to-get-an-asp-net-mvc-ajax-response-to-redirect-to-new-page-instead-of-inser?lq=1)

is tried to fix it, but this causes other error: browser tries to open url `window.location = '/Checkout/CompleteOK'`

How to fix this exception? Everything looks OK, there is no partial views as described in other answers.
I tried als o to use method='post' attribute in form but problem persists.

Comment: It is not related to your question, but do you realize that in your PaymentByBankTransfer action the code after the first return is not reachable?

Comment: yes. Code after first return shows another unsuccesful attempt to resolve the issue using code from other, referenced answer. It is better to avoid this javascipt injection, first return should work. I asked why first return causes this stange error, probably in RedirectToAction method call

Comment: Have you tried `return RedirectToAction("Complete");` directly from `PaymentByBankTransfer()` ? Do you have the same error or do you achieve the desired behavior ?

Comment: I tried but still got `Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.` exception.

Comment: They "complete" action, renders a PartialView or a View?

Comment: It renders View. I updated question and added Complete method code.

Comment: I had this problem and after many search and tries I found the problem is in related controller method (calling action same as PaymentByBankTransfer here). It had an error but not thrown proper exception and I just got famous error "Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions", So after handle and repair the error problem gone away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of Calling `public ActionResult CheckoutCompleteOK()` on post, remove that action and Create a HTTP Post Action for `public ActionResult PaymentByBankTransfer()`.

Then return `RedirectToAction("Complete");` in PaymentByBankTransfer post method.

I think this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Without using javascript for redirect:**
If you put forms inside your child view,Sometimes if you specify action name and controller name in Beginform helper(inside child view), this problem doesn't happen. for example I changed my child action view like this :

Before :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 ...
}
```

After :

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("InsertComment", "Comments", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "commentform" })) 
{
 ...
}
```

Now, You can put RedirectAction command inside "InsertComment" action and everything will work.