# Redirect Partial View to login page when session expires

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Is there a simple way to redirect the entire page (not just the partial view) to the login page after the session has expired?

I have tried the following solutions, but can't get it to work:

- [.Net MVC Partial View load login page when session expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553871/net-mvc-partial-view-load-login-page-when-session-expires)
- [How to redirect full page rather then only partial view changing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541230/how-to-redirect-full-page-rather-then-only-partial-view-changing)

My problem is that the partial view redirects to the Login-page, and not the entire page (same problem as in the links).

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult LogPartialView(string a, int? b, string c, string d, int? e, string f)
        {
            //If the user is "Admin" -> display Logs for all customers.
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, "Admin"))
            {
                if (Session["myID"] == null)
                {
                    ExpireSession();
                }
            //Some code

        return PartialView("LogPartialLayout", model);
        }
```

I wanted to return Redirect ("~/") if myID is null but it doesnt work since it expects a Partial View.

Error-message: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult'

```
public void ExpireSession()
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        WebSecurity.Logout();
        Response.Redirect("~/");

    }
```

[image: Picture of the view]

Comment: Change the signature of your method to: `public ActionResult LogPartialView(...)`

Comment: @haim770 I added if session = null -> Redirect ("~/")
But it still redirects inside the partial view.

Comment: @haim770 ..I forgot to mention that I changed to public ActionResult, but with no success. Still redirects inside the PartialView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to build on @EmilChirambattu s answer.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogPartialView(string a, int? b, string c, string d, int? e, string f)
{
    // You should check the session before anything else.
    if (Session["myID"] == null)
    {
        return ExpireSession();
    }

    //If the user is "Admin" -> display Logs for all customers.
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, "Admin"))
    {
        //Some code
    }

    return PartialView("LogPartialLayout", model);
}

public void ExpireSession()
{
    Session.Abandon();
    WebSecurity.Logout();
    Response.Redirect("RedirectToLogin");
}

public ActionResult RedirectToLogin()
{
    return PartialView("_RedirectToLogin");
}
```

**_RedirectToLogin View**

```
<script>
    window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "")';
</script>
```

This should redirect you to the base URL of the page (most likely your login-page).

Answer (score 2):

Web Config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/RedirectToLogin" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Account Controller

```
public ActionResult RedirectToLogin()
{
    return PartialView("_RedirectToLogin");
}
```

_RedirectToLogin View

```
<script>
    window.location = '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")';
</script>
```

something like that, change the URLs accordingly