# RedirectToAction not working in IE(Internet Explorer - 8+) MVC4 Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have one Event page and after creation of new event (Create action call), i am redirecting to Index method of that Event controller.

I have used Ajax from to post data to controller.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Events", new AjaxOptions
            {
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"
            }, new { @id = "updateEventForm" }))
            {
```

while saving data successfully to server, it will call "**updateSuccess**" javascript method , in which i get whole index page as html in data as parameter as below,

```
function updateSuccess(data)
{
   console.log(data);
}
```

I just need to get all updated data from server in the form of html by this Index method call,

**Index Method :**

```
public ActionResult Index(int SubscriptionID = 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    return PartialView(Events.GetAllEventsWithoutSubscription());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }    
            }
```

**Create Method :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Events objEvents)
        {
            try
            {
                int Result = CreateEvent(objEvents);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { SubscriptionID = objEvents.SubscriptionID });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

**I don't want to redirect to index. I just want to get updated HTML by Index to update Index table only by jquery.**
but in IE8+ versions, RedirectAction is not called somehow.
Please help as soon as possible.

Comment: try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538523/how-to-get-an-asp-net-mvc-ajax-response-to-redirect-to-new-page-instead-of-inser

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this by AJAX, why don't you just return the result of the `Index` method?:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Events objEvents)
{
    try
    {
        int Result = CreateEvent(objEvents);
        return Index(SubscriptionID = objEvents.SubscriptionID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
 }
```

This way, your browser won't have to do an additional request to the server to get the results. `RedirectToAction` is usefult if your making a POST request the traditional way (without AJAX) and don't want your users to send the form again if they push the refresh button of press `F5`. But with AJAX you won't have this problem.

Comment: int Result = CreateEvent(objEvents);
return Index(objEvents.SubscriptionID);

I have already tried out this, but it will be redirected to Create and Index, means infinite loop is going on.