# RedirectToAction with Ajax.Beginform , unexpected results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, ajax.beginform

I have the following view , which contains an Ajax.BeginForm:-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeDevicesSwitch", "Switch", new AjaxOptions

{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
    UpdateTargetId = "result",
    LoadingElementId = "progress2",
    HttpMethod= "POST"
    ,
    OnSuccess = "createsuccess",
    OnFailure = "createfail"




}))
//code goes here
<p><img src="~/Content/Ajax-loader-bar.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress2" /></p>
<div id ="result"></div>
```

and the following Action Method which will be called from the Ajax.Bginform:-

```
public ActionResult ChangeDevicesSwitch(SwitchJoin s)

        {//code goes here
            try
            {
                var count = repository.changeDeviceSwitch(s.Switch.SwitchID, (Int32)s.GeneralSwitchTo, User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1));
                repository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = s.GeneralSwitchTo });

            }
            catch (Exception e)

            {
                return Json(new { IsSuccess = "custome", description = "Error occurred. Please check...." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }



        }
```

The script which will run when the Ajax.BeginForm return success is :-

```
function createsuccess(data) {
    if (data.IsSuccess == "Unauthorized") {

        jAlert(data.description, 'Unauthorized Access');
    }
    else if (data.IsSuccess == "False") {

        jAlert('Error Occurred. ' + data.description, 'Error');
    }
    else if (data.IsSuccess == "custome") {

        alert(data.description);

    }
    else  {
        jAlert('Record added Successfully ', 'Creation Confirmation');
    }

}
```

currently i am facing a problem is that when the RedirectToAction is reach ,, the whole view will be displayed inside the current view!! so is there a way to force my application not to update the target if an RedirecttoAction is returned ?

Comment: You can not make a redirect via ajax. Instead you can send the redirect url back to the client and on `createsuccess` function set the `window.location` to the provided url.

Comment: can you advice more on this with a sample code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Return the url you want to make a redirect to from the action method when the operation succeeded:

```
public ActionResult ChangeDevicesSwitch(SwitchJoin s)
{
    try
    {
        ...
        return Json(new { RedirectUrl = Url.Action("Details", new { id = s.GeneralSwitchTo }) });
    }
    ...
}
```

And in the `createsuccess`:

```
function createsuccess(data) {
    if (data.RedirectUrl)
        window.location.href = data.RedirectUrl;
}
```

Comment: here is **one liner** `return JavaScript( "window.location = '" + Url.Action("Home","Details") + "'" )` check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538523/how-to-get-an-asp-net-mvc-ajax-response-to-redirect-to-new-page-instead-of-inser), hope helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, following method was worked

```
function OnSuccess(data) {
    var json;
        if (data.responseText instanceof Object)
            json = data.responseText;
        else
            json = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);

        if (json.RedirectUrl)
            window.location.href = json.RedirectUrl;
}
```