# RediretToAction doesn't work - MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to another action but it's not working.
The action is called but the return View() doesn't change the screen.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel vm)
{
     return RedirectToAction("AlterarSenhaPadrao", new { Id = usuario.Id });
}

public ViewResult AlterarSenhaPadrao(int Id)
{
    return View(new AlterarSenhaViewModel { UsuarioId = Id });
}
```

Looking at the Developer Tools on Chrome, I get this:

[image]

So, the action is called but it doesn't return the view properly. By the way, my controller is not assigned with [Authorize].
Any ideia about why is this happening?

Thanks

UPDATE

```
//Shows the login page
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View(new LoginViewModel());
}

//The submit action, the same I posted below.
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel vm)
{

}
```

And my login page:
[image]

Comment: and how do you call Login action?

Comment: My form on Login.cshtml calls this action on submit. I have another "HttpGet Login" action to return the login page aswell.

Comment: Can you please post an example?

Comment: I updated my question!

Comment: Where you have defined usuario in the post method?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `UpdateTargetId` in your ajax options.
Sinde your request is ajax, you tell the framework where to display your response.
Try

```
new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "mydiv"})
```

Comment: It didn't work! I added this: @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divContainerBody" } ... ))

Comment: I don't know if the problem is to redirect to a HttpGet action from a HttpPost action. 'Cause I tried from Get to Get and it worked!

Comment: try `return View("AlterarSenhaPadrao", new AlterarSenhaViewModel { UsuarioId = Id });` instead redirect to action in your POST login view.

Comment: do you have a fiddler to check exact response of your request?

Comment: No, I don't have one!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786838/redirecttoaction-with-ajax-beginform-unexpected-results) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391201/ajax-beginform-that-can-redirect-to-a-new-page) you will need to pass back the url that you want to redirect to and then perform the redirect in JavaScript.

So your post action would be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel vm)
{
     return Json(new { RedirectUrl = Url.Action("AlterarSenhaPadrao", new { Id = usuario.Id }) });
}
```

And then your call to ajax:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "YourControllerName", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSuccess", ... }))
{
    ...
}
```

And then finally your JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var onSuccess = function(result) {
        if (result.url) {
            // if the server returned a JSON object containing an url 
            // property we redirect the browser to that url
            window.location.href = result.url;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Well, so it's easyer to return a JavaScript("window.location.href = result.url;") right?

Comment: @DeiseVicentin - I believe that with the way you are currently calling the http post action, that the MVC will return a redirect http response as you expect, but the inline JavaScript that handles the request does not know how to handle the response that is returned.  That is why you have to perform the redirect yourself in JavaScript.  This seems to be pretty standard practise.  If you google around for "mvc ajax handle redirect" then you will find various users having the same problem and suggesting the same solution.  Hope this helps.